# TTK : Unreasonable behavior of sizegrip

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

unfortunately, i have some problems with my gui as the behavior of the sizegrip
for items inside of frames is, for me, inexplicable. I have this simple code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

Example_Standard_Window = tk.Tk( screenName = None  ,
                                 baseName   = None  ,
                                 className  = 'Tk'  ,
                                 useTk      = True  ,
                                 sync       = False ,
                                 use        = None  )

Example_Standard_Window.title( 'Testumgebung' )
Example_Standard_Window.geometry( '400x300' )
Example_Standard_Window.resizable( True , True )

Example_Standard_Window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
Example_Standard_Window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

var_3 = tk.IntVar( value = 2 )

Example_Menu = tk.Menu( Example_Standard_Window ) 
Example_Standard_Window.config( menu = Example_Menu )

file_menu = tk.Menu( Example_Menu ,  tearoff = False )
Example_Menu.add_cascade( label = "File", menu = file_menu )

Example_Standard_Window.sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(Example_Standard_Window)
Example_Standard_Window.sizegrip.grid( row = 100, column = 100, padx = ( 0 , 5 ) , pady = ( 0 , 5 ) , sticky = 'ew' )


Example_FRM = ttk.Frame( Example_Standard_Window , 
                      #  height    = 520         ,   
                      #  width     = 520         ,
                         padding   = 5           ,
                         border    = 1           ,
                         cursor    = 'boat'      ,
                         relief    = 'sunken'    ,   # Flat , Groove , Raised , Ridge , Solid Or Sunken
                         style     = None        ,
                         takefocus = True       )  
 
Example_FRM.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=(0, 5) , sticky='nsew' )
 
radio_1 = ttk.Radiobutton( Example_FRM, text="Selected", variable=var_3, value = 1 )
radio_1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0, 5), pady=(0, 5) , sticky='nsew' )

Example_Standard_Window.mainloop( )
```

I guess you have to execute the code to know, what i'm talking about. But i also try to explain it.

If i use the sizegrip icon on the right bottom of the window, the radio button inside the frame disappears as soon as i'm resizing it. BUT if i use the usual cursor tool, it doesn't. What's the problem here ?? It has to have something to do with the frame, but i can't figure out how to configure it properly.

[image]

One adddional question :
For my understanding, it's only possible to create
responsible windows with grid( ), so it's not possible
with place( ) ?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro , 64 Bit , Python 3.9.6.

I hope, you have some hints on that.

Best regards
NumeroUnoDE

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening, maybe because `radiobutton` is not updating during the resizing of the `sizegrip`. But I know how to "fix" it. Add this: `Example_Standard_Window.sizegrip.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: radio_1.configure(state=radio_1['state']))`. This "updates" `radiobutton`. When `sizegrip`  is resizing, I am setting one of the `radiobutton` parameter to the same value it has, which doesn't actually change it.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I will try to implement your solution, but that means, that i have to do this for every element of the frame ? It has definitly something to do with the focus on the radiobutton :(

Comment: The size grip seems to work fine for me on my OSX machine. The radiobutton doesn't disappear when I resize the window using the grip.

Comment: You can create responsive GUIs with `place`, but it requires a lot of work. `pack` and `grid` are much easier for creating responsive GUIs. With place you can use relative positioning (relx, rely) and relative sizes (relwidth, relheight) to get responsive behavior. For example, you can use `place` with the size grip like this to put it in the bottom right corner: `Example_Standard_Window.sizegrip.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")`